# Issue Adding and Authenticating SSH Keys for Collaborator

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm setting up a git repo to use SSH access instead of HTTPS, and I'm running into a few issues.

I've generated keys properly and added the public key to the GitHub user's account properly. I know that the keys are correct because I have successfully added SSH access for this particular user on a test server.

I also have correctly set the remote url (i.e. git@github.com:user/project.git), although this was done before any key nonsense took place.

Here is what I have done so far on the production server.
I have created the `~/.ssh/config` file in the directory on the the user that OWNS the local repository. I added the Host, HostName, User and IdentityFile EXACTLY as they appear in the production server. Then I attempted to authenticate the key and ran into an error: First I ran `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`. This worked and spat out the PID. I then ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and permission was denied. I then sudo'd that command and got an error:

"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

I found this to be really odd and was able to find a solution that involved running

`sudo ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Which prompted me for the key password, which I entered and got the message that the key was added.

On the test server this seemed to be all that needed to be done. However when I test the connection on the production server using `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the message "Hello WRONG_USER...". Where WRONG_USER is an old user that no longer has access rights to the repo. I know that this user has no access because running `git pull origin master` gives me an "Error: Repository Not Found" when the repository definitely exists.

Can anybody figure out what exactly it is I'm doing wrong? I'm suspicious of maybe file permissions being wonky and that affecting the key authentication. I don't know why I had to sudo the `ssh-add` command.

My goal is to see github's "Hello CORRECT_USER..." when I run `ssh -T git@github.com` where CORRECT_USER is the user that I'm currently adding keys for.

I will be happy to provide additional information if any is needed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do a `ssh -Tv git@github.com` and check it does use the expected private key. Then check if the public key is not already registered in OLD_USER GitHub SSH seeting page.

Comment: Thanks. It ended up being an issue with the config file. I'm still fairly new to this kind of stuff, so knowing about the -v flag for ssh is going to com in handy. I was able to fix the issue.